# Auth0 Android - How to renew id_token?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, openid, amazon-cognito, auth0

I have Auth0 and cognito all wired up.  I can login to the app and everything works great.  Until the `id_token` expires, then everything fails.

What is the ODIC Conformant way to refresh/renew `id_tokens`?

The following code only refreshes the access token for me.

Initial auth:

```
 WebAuthProvider.login(auth0CredentialsManager.getAuth0Account())
                .withScope("openid email profile offline_access") // is offline_access required?
                .withResponseType(ResponseType.ID_TOKEN | ResponseType.CODE | ResponseType.TOKEN) // I'm not sure if this is necessary to specify...
                .withParameters(params)
                .withAudience(String.format("https://%s/userinfo", BuildConfig.AUTH0_DOMAIN))
                .start(Auth0LoginActivity.this, new AuthCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Dialog dialog) {
                        // Show error Dialog to user
                        dialog.show();
                        onAuth0Failure(null);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(AuthenticationException exception) {
                        Bugsnag.notify(exception);
                        onAuth0Failure(exception);
                        // Show error to user
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull Credentials credentials) {
                        handleSignIn(credentials); //this call saves credentials using SecureCredentialsManager.  If you want to see it let me know
                    }
                });
```

And when I need to get a fresh `id_token`, I'm trying this (but it only refreshes the access token):

```
        // auth0CredentialsManager is SecureCredentialsManager
        auth0CredentialsManager.getCredentials(new BaseCallback<Credentials, CredentialsManagerException>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Credentials credentials) {
                auth0CredentialsManager.saveCredentials(credentials);
                //  do more stuff here... except the id_token is expired (access token is not).
            }
```

Do I:

- Need to request `offline_access` or is that only for `access tokens`?  (in my testing, it appears to only refresh access tokens).

Research/Things I've tried:

- https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/ seems to indicate I just set `openid` scope, but I'm doing that and only getting the intial id_token.  Do I need to refresh the token with `prompt=none` parameters and make another login call?  https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication seems to indicate silent login is only needed for single page applications though.
- `AuthenticationAPIClient.delegationWithRefreshToken` looks like it would be the right call to make, but it always throws `com.auth0.android.authentication.AuthenticationException: An error occurred when trying to authenticate with the server.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's what I've learned.

As of version 1.18.0, the call to `getCredentials` does *NOT* consider id token expiration.  It *only* checks if the access token is expired, and if it is, it will then refresh the `id_token` and `access token`.  Unfortunately the `access token` expiry is locked in at 24 hours unless you do additional work.

Make sure you have `setOIDCCompliant` to `true` when you create your Auth0Account instance, or else the call to renew will hit the `/delegation` endpoint which is now deprecated and only works if your client id is setup to support non oidc compliant calls.

One other thing to be aware of that's somewhat off topic.  The `SecureCredentialsManager` clears out credentials if anything appears to go wrong.  This isn't acceptable for me, as simply being offline and being unable to make the call causes the credentials to be cleared.